# Angels saying Shirah before Hashem - "daily" rituals?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, time, malach-angel, vayishlach

Rashi on [Gen 32.27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.32.27?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.32.27.1-2&lang2=bi&p3=Bereishit_Rabbah.78&lang3=bi)

> כי עלה השחר. וְצָרִיךְ אֲנִי לוֹמַר שִׁירָה בַּיּוֹם (חולין צ"א):
>
> כי עלה השחר FOR THE DAY BREAKETH, and I have **to sing God’s praise at day** (Chullin 91b; Genesis Rabbah 78:1).

When we have daily rituals, it's because we're dependent on Sun's cycle, but IIRC, G-d is far beyond Sun and stars, so He should have any daily cycle for Himself, only what's related to Jewish rituals.

So why do angels and G-d have Sun-related rituals?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.3b.7?lang=bi